# php. what is different between this two functions?

Tags: php, mysqli

what is different between this functions in php.
example_1.

```
$get = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM myTable"));
```

and this type.
example_2.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
$get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
```

my question is (did different speed between this two type in write code ?).

Comment: run a benchmark and see for yourself

Comment: If it's not worth profiling, it's not worth asking. Also you know, any syntax variation on PHPs end pales in comparison to querying the database in the first place.

Comment: the real question is: does it involve user input and if your query does take an possible sql injection into account? the question's too broad *and unclear*, IMHO, since we don't know that and if you're echoing a whole bunch of stuff elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is the coding style. Example 1 is harder to read then example 2. Speed differences are non-existent, as these are the same commands.